# How to change color of a TextView line by line?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I have text that goes like that:

- loading item 1
- loading item 2
- loading item 3

I want to change color (or fontWeight) of every line to show user the progress.

Comment: use [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) for this

```
val currentText = textView.text
val spannable = SpannableString(currentText)
spannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, endOfFirstLine, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
spannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), endOfFirstLine, endOfSecondLine, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
spannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), endOfSecondLine, endOfThirdLine, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

// Set the colored text
textView.text = spannable
```